# casting int32_t to std::complex<float>

Tags: c++, casting, transform, memcpy

I receive some data over a wire protocol. One of the packets I receive has some int32_t values that represent complex numbers.  i.e.  10 complex numbers come in the form of 20 int32_t values (real,imag).

I need to convert the int32_t's to float's and copy these values into a vector<std::complex<float>>.  I am not sure of the preferred method to do this.

this works but sure is ugly and highly questionable.  This is a sudo realtime system and I need as fast an operation as possible.

```
float coefBuffer[20];
std::transform(packet.coef,packet.coef+20,coefBuffer, [](int32_t x) { return (float)x;});
std::memcpy(complexFloatVector.data(),coefBuffer,sizeof(float)*20);
```

I tried many kinds of casting and could not come up with a better solution.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you timed this section? How long it takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it

```
complexFloatVector.resize(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    complexFloatVector[i] = std::complex<float>((float)(packet.coef[i * 2]), (float)(packet.coef[i * 2 + 1]));
}
```

I'm assuming `complexFloatVector` is a `std::vector<std::complex<float>>` type and `packet.coef` is an array of 20 integers.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```cpp
for ( uint32_t j=0; j<10; ++j ) {
    complexFloatVector[j] = std::complex<float>(packet.coef[2*j],packet.coef[2*j+1]);
}
```